# x86 assembly: Why am I getting the error undefined symbol: DumpMem?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32, undefined-symbol

I am just starting out learning assembly. I am calling DumpMem to display the array, however I am getting the error undefined symbol: DumpMem. I was under the assumption DumpMem should be included in the Irvine 32 library, which was imported. Can anyone be so kind as to suggest what may be going wrong here? Thank you.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall 
.stack 4096
includelib irvine32.lib
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
arrayfib DWORD 35 DUP (99h)

.code
main PROC 
mov eax, 0          
mov edi, 1           

L1: 
sub ebp, 2
cmp ebp, 0 
js FINISH
add eax, edi
add edi, eax
LOOP L1


FINISH:
test eax, 1 
jz FINISHEVEN
mov edx, eax
ret    

FINISHEVEN:
mov edx, edi
ret

mov esi, OFFSET arrayfib
mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrayfib 
mov ebx, TYPE arrayfib 
call DumpMem

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Looks okay. Did you get a warning maybe about `irvine32.lib` not being found? Can you call other functions from it, e.g. `WriteInt`?

Comment: How did you run the assembler and linker?

Comment: Irvine32 does include that: http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/dumpmem.htm.  If you're getting linker errors for it, showing just your source code isn't a [mcve].